# Is there a better way to find duplicate rows _including_ the first/last?

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

Consider a Pandas data frame:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': pd.Series([1,1,1,2,3]),
    'b': pd.Series(list('asdfg'))
})
```

I want to return all of the rows with duplicate values for column `a`, including the first or last row. I can do this with

```
df[df['a'].duplicated() | df['a'].duplicated(take_last=True)]
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Do you want only first and last row of `a` or all duplicates for `a`?

Comment: @JohnGalt all of them, so the first three rows of the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `count` occurrences of `a` and return `values>1` for duplicated rows.

```
In [25]: df[(df.groupby('a').transform('count')>1).values]
Out[25]:
   a  b
0  1  a
1  1  s
2  1  d
```

Comment: I ran some benchmarks and it turns out this is 100x slower (on a data frame with ~ 500 rows) than my original solution. Not a big deal in my case but interesting.

Comment: Yes. `duplicated()` is a faster and more direct implementation in Cython, read [Wes's blog](http://wesmckinney.com/blog/filtering-out-duplicate-dataframe-rows/) on this.