# R remove row that are not duplicated from a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have some data that looks like:

```
> data<-data.frame(x=c(1,1,2,3,4,2,2), y=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,8))
  x y
1 1 1
2 1 2
3 2 3
4 3 4
5 4 5
6 2 6
7 2 8
```

I'm using duplicate in the next way:

```
data[duplicated(data[,1]), ]
```

And I'm getting:

```
  x y
2 1 2
6 2 6
7 2 8
```

I would like:

```
  x y
1 1 1    
2 1 2
3 2 3
6 2 6
7 2 8
```

Comment: Funnily enough, I just asked the Python version of this question the other day: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30808703/2954547

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a value is duplicated m times in a vector, the first incidence is not marked as a duplicate by `duplicated` and the subsequent m-1 values are marked as duplicates. To get all m duplicates, I will usually use `duplicated(...) | duplicated(..., fromLast=TRUE)`:

```
data[duplicated(data[,1]) | duplicated(data[,1], fromLast=TRUE),]
#   x y
# 1 1 1
# 2 1 2
# 3 2 3
# 6 2 6
# 7 2 8
```

Answer (score 0):

In `data.table` I'd do:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data,key="x")
data[.(data[duplicated(data),unique(x)])]
```

Or even simpler:

```
setDT(data)[,if (.N>1) .SD,by=x]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
subset(data, x %in% x[duplicated(x)])
```